# extjs tree panel with sequence numbering

Tags: extjs

Requirement : My Tree panel items/elements should have numbering system

```
1. Master Pack
 1.1. Acceptance
      1.1.1. Client
      1.1.2. Mission
1.2. Planning
       1.2.1. Fieldwork 1
       1.2.2. Fieldwork 2
1.3. Completion
       1.3.1. End of Audit Memo
```

Comment: You could create a custom field using the `convert` method of `Ext.data.field.Field` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might only server as a guide, you will have to tweak it to get to your desired requirement. So basically I am looping through the records and check if the node has any children or not: `parent` is basically your record.

```
Ext.each(parent, function(node) {
    if (node.children !== null && node.children.length !== 0) {
        // Number the current node         
        this.numberMyNodes(node.children);        //Call itself if to number the children.
    } else {
        //this node has no children
    }
});
```